# Exception when using custom session factory implementation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring with Hibernate for transaction management. For SessionFactory, I have a custom implementation class HRSessionFactory as below:

```
package com.practice.swh.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.Reference;

import org.hibernate.Cache;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionBuilder;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.StatelessSession;
import org.hibernate.StatelessSessionBuilder;
import org.hibernate.TypeHelper;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.FilterDefinition;
import org.hibernate.metadata.ClassMetadata;
import org.hibernate.metadata.CollectionMetadata;
import org.hibernate.stat.Statistics;

public class HRSessionFactory implements SessionFactory {

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public void close() throws HibernateException {     
    sessionFactory.close();
}

@Override
public void evict(Class arg0, Serializable arg1) throws HibernateException {
    sessionFactory.evict(arg0, arg1);
}

@Override
public void evict(Class arg0) throws HibernateException {
    sessionFactory.evict(arg0);
}

@Override
public void evictCollection(String arg0, Serializable arg1) throws HibernateException {
    sessionFactory.evictCollection(arg0, arg1);
}

@Override
public void evictCollection(String arg0) throws HibernateException {
    sessionFactory.evictCollection(arg0);
}

@Override
public void evictEntity(String arg0, Serializable arg1) throws HibernateException {
    sessionFactory.evictEntity(arg0, arg1);
}

@Override
public void evictEntity(String arg0) throws HibernateException {
    sessionFactory.evictEntity(arg0);
}

@Override
public void evictQueries() throws HibernateException {
    sessionFactory.evictQueries();
}

@Override
public void evictQueries(String arg0) throws HibernateException {
    sessionFactory.evictQueries(arg0);
}

@Override
public Map getAllClassMetadata() throws HibernateException {
    return sessionFactory.getAllClassMetadata();
}

@Override
public Map getAllCollectionMetadata() throws HibernateException {
    return sessionFactory.getAllCollectionMetadata();
}

@Override
public ClassMetadata getClassMetadata(Class arg0) throws HibernateException {
    return sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(arg0);
}

@Override
public ClassMetadata getClassMetadata(String arg0) throws HibernateException {
    return sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(arg0);
}

@Override
public CollectionMetadata getCollectionMetadata(String arg0) throws HibernateException {
    return sessionFactory.getCollectionMetadata(arg0);
}

@Override
public Session getCurrentSession() throws HibernateException {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

@Override
public Set getDefinedFilterNames() {
    return sessionFactory.getDefinedFilterNames();
}

@Override
public FilterDefinition getFilterDefinition(String arg0) throws HibernateException {
    return sessionFactory.getFilterDefinition(arg0);
}

@Override
public Statistics getStatistics() {
    return sessionFactory.getStatistics();
}

@Override
public boolean isClosed() {
    return sessionFactory.isClosed();
}

@Override
public Session openSession() throws HibernateException {
    return sessionFactory.openSession();
}

@Override
public StatelessSession openStatelessSession() {
    return sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
}

@Override
public StatelessSession openStatelessSession(Connection arg0) {
    return sessionFactory.openStatelessSession(arg0);
}

@Override
public Reference getReference() throws NamingException {
    return sessionFactory.getReference();
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(sessionFactory.hashCode());
}

@Override
public boolean containsFetchProfileDefinition(String arg0) {
    return sessionFactory.containsFetchProfileDefinition(arg0);
}

@Override
public Cache getCache() {
    return sessionFactory.getCache();
}

@Override
public SessionFactoryOptions getSessionFactoryOptions() {
    return sessionFactory.getSessionFactoryOptions();
}

@Override
public TypeHelper getTypeHelper() {
    return sessionFactory.getTypeHelper();
}

@Override
public SessionBuilder withOptions() {
    return sessionFactory.withOptions();
}

@Override
public StatelessSessionBuilder withStatelessOptions() {
    return sessionFactory.withStatelessOptions();
}
}
```

My application context is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/disautomation"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="com.practice.swh.entity.HRSessionFactory">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mySessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>employee.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="executeQuery*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" rollback-for="Exception"/>
        <tx:method name="*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="txPointCut" expression="execution(* com.practice.swh.manager..*.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="txPointCut" />
</aop:config>

<bean id="employeeDao" class="com.practice.swh.dao.impl.EmployeeDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="employeeManager" class="com.practice.swh.manager.impl.EmployeeManagerImpl">
    <property name="employeeDao" ref="employeeDao"></property>
    <property name="dummyManager" ref="dummyManager"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Manager implementation:

```
package com.practice.swh.manager.impl;

import com.practice.swh.dao.EmployeeDao;
import com.practice.swh.entity.Employee;
import com.practice.swh.manager.EmployeeManager;

public class EmployeeManagerImpl implements EmployeeManager {

private EmployeeDao employeeDao;

@Override
public Employee getEmployee(Integer employeeId) {
    Employee employee = employeeDao.getEmployee(employeeId);
    //System.out.println(employee.getDepartment());
    //System.out.println(employee.getAddresses());
    return employee;
}

public EmployeeDao getEmployeeDao() {
    return employeeDao;
}

public void setEmployeeDao(EmployeeDao employeeDao) {
    this.employeeDao = employeeDao;
}

}
```

Dao Implementation:

```
package com.practice.swh.dao.impl;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import com.practice.swh.dao.EmployeeDao;
import com.practice.swh.entity.Employee;

public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public Employee getEmployee(Integer employeeId) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    return (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, employeeId);
}

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

}
```

My test class :

```
package com.practice.swh.client;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.practice.swh.entity.Employee;
import com.practice.swh.manager.EmployeeManager;

public class EmployeeTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    getEmployeeTest();
}

private static void getEmployeeTest() {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    EmployeeManager employeeManager = (EmployeeManager) ctx.getBean("employeeManager");
    Employee employee = employeeManager.getEmployee(4);
    System.out.println(employee);
}

}
```

When I execute the test class, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:883)
at com.practice.swh.entity.HRSessionFactory.getCurrentSession(HRSessionFactory.java:100)
at com.practice.swh.dao.impl.EmployeeDaoImpl.getEmployee(EmployeeDaoImpl.java:34)
at com.practice.swh.manager.impl.EmployeeManagerImpl.getEmployee(EmployeeManagerImpl.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.getEmployee(Unknown Source)
at com.practice.swh.client.EmployeeTest.getEmployeeTest(EmployeeTest.java:35)
at com.practice.swh.client.EmployeeTest.main(EmployeeTest.java:12)
```

However, the code works fine when I change the application context to not use the custom session factory as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/disautomation"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>

<!-- <bean id="sessionFactory" class="com.practice.swh.entity.HRSessionFactory">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean> -->

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>employee.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>department.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>employeeAddress.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="executeQuery*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" rollback-for="Exception"/>
        <tx:method name="*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="txPointCut" expression="execution(* com.practice.swh.manager..*.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="txPointCut" />
</aop:config>

<bean id="employeeDao" class="com.practice.swh.dao.impl.EmployeeDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="employeeManager" class="com.practice.swh.manager.impl.EmployeeManagerImpl">
    <property name="employeeDao" ref="employeeDao"></property>
    <property name="dummyManager" ref="dummyManager"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

What is the issue if I use a custom SessionFactory implementation?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code:
First. You have to use `@Autowire` annotation when injecting Spring beans to be able to use them properly.
Second. When you are using transaction manager with `sessionFactory` you should annotate service or dao method with `@Transaction` annotation

Try that and see if it helps

Comment: As I said above, the code works fine if i change the applicationContext as mentioned above. I am not using Annotations and my manager is Transactional as it satisfies the pointcut expression.